# Looking for examples for error handling on Paypal payment status code (other than 201)?

Tags: paypal

Hello Paypal experience experts,

Since about 5 months I'm trying to implementate version /v2 of the Paypal payment SDK.

I am looking for examples of what you should tell a customer what to do when receiving an error code in the Paypal payment response status code (HTTP?), other than 201.

I'm using the Paypal javascript SDK and PHP SDK with CreateOrder.php and CaptureOrder.php.
A basic test in the sandbox does function okay.

In PHP I will use a self created object from the Paypal response for easier error handling on the client side.

The only example which Paypal gives on their site is about code 422 'Instrument Declined'.

However Paypal also shows a number of other status codes, like 200, 202, 204, 4xx.

To be able to complete my error handling script I would like to have some examples of what the customer should do if any of the other error codes occur.

I would have expected that Paypal would have given those examples, but they seem not to exist (Paypal assumes they will not occur (?) ).

(There are other questions on this forum that look similar, but they are not about /v2)

Can somebody please help me with those examples?

Thank you in advance.

Martin

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/responses/   ?  But what exactly to report to your user(s) is up to you ...

Answer (score 0):

The best error-handling example for a server-based integration is at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

This shows how to restart with client-side JS in the case of the recoverable instrument declined. For all other cases, it simply shows the error message details returned. If you want to show a different message, you can customize it to your needs, but it is not necessary. The important thing is that in the case of errors you do still return some details from the backend to the frontend that your frontend knows what to do with, which is particularly important for the case of INSTRUMENT_DECLINED.

---

Other possible error types are documented toward the end of each API reference, for the case of the Orders API [that can be found here.](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/orders/v2/errors/)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I know about https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server. Other error types at https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/orders/v2/errors/ shows the error name, description and issue when a 4xx error occurs. These are not mentioned for a customer. About the status codes 200, 202 and 204 Paypal gives only a description on their site. Unfortunately, it's still unknown which action should be taken when one of those occur. Do you know?

Comment: For non-5xx errors status code isn't what's important, the details of the error is. Show a message. For 5xx errors you could implement some sort of delayed retry, if you want. Idempotency is useful here. https://developer.paypal.com/reference/guidelines/idempotency/

Comment: Thank you.
About 5xx errors Idempotency could be usefull indeed.
About the codes 200, 202, 204 you also do not know what to do then?
I think those codes will be sent for a reason and some action needs to be taken.
I have really no idea what will happen when doing nothing on receiving one of those codes.

Comment: 2xx are HTTP success responses. However the HTTP status is not what is important, process the contents of the body looking for a resulting capture id and correct amount, etc

Comment: Thank you again.
If the 2xx codes are not important, then why is Paypal mention those (https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/responses/) ?
The codes mean:
- 200: 'The request succeeded.'
  Not very helpful.
- 202: 'The server accepted the request and will execute it later.'
  But how much later, seconds, minutes, hours ..?
- 204: 'The server successfully executed the method but returns no response body.'
  When could this happen?
According your answer, does that mean that those codes not would happen on a normal payment transaction?
202 would happen on a payment refund transaction?

Comment: When things could happen depends on the API. The body of the response is what's important. Some operations return no content, in which case the status will be 204. An example is a patch. The relevant details for non-5xx cases are documented in each API.